# What class name should I use for a class use to CRUD with some data type in nodejs

Tags: node.js, oop, orm, architecture

In many case, I need write a lot of class work with CRUD for some class. For example CRUD with pure object User, Book, Tag.

I usually make a directory named `models`, put all the CRUD classed into the models folder.

But I feel that the word `model` is not show essence. Is the word `model` well-defined in computer science? It means the pure object of User, or the means of CRUD of User?

I also use another name `services` for more complex logic, For example UserService may require other `models` than UserModel. But the word `service` is often conflict with some other case like an online service, backend service.

Are there any good names for the model and service in my case? BTW, I am most using Node.js; it may not conflict with the general conventions used in Node.js.

Comment: Model is a commonly used term to describe the classes that represent the data being displayed to the user. You see it commonly in the UI patterns like MVP, MVC, and MVVM. In each of those cases, the M stands for model.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, it will come down to what makes the code the most understandable both to you and to someone down the road who may have occasion to work on your code.  If 'model' and 'services' convey the thought of what lies within in an obvious way to anyone coming in to the code, then they are probably fine.  As far as standards, I don't know if there is a 'defined' set of names you have to use.  In MVC, for example, you will use 'Models' as one of your folders in order to store all of the actual models you will be feeding your views, and this is understood in the MVC architecture that those names (Models, Views, Controllers) are the standard.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that `Model` is a little ambiguous. Sometimes it is used to indicate domain objects such as User/Book/Tag, but sometimes it is used to indicate objects that deal with business logic, such as "Buying a book","Authenticating a user". 
What's common to both uses is that "Model" is clearly separated from UI, that is handled entirely by the Views and the Controllers.

Another useful name is **Entities**. In Robert Martin's work on Object Oriented Design, he speaks of use-case-driven design, and distinguishes between three kinds of objects: Entity Objects, Interactor objects and Boundary objects.

`Entity objects` are useful in multiple use-cases. For example, in a book selling system, entities can be `Book`/`User`/`Recommendation`/`Review`.

`Interactor objects` implement use-cases, and they typically use multiple entity objects. For example, `Purchase_Book`/`Login`/`Search_Books` can be such objects.

`Boundary objects` are used for transferring data across module boundaries, and are used for building interfaces between parts of the system, which should be decoupled from one-another. For example, a controller may need to create a `Purchase_Book` object, and in order to create it, it needs to pass data about what book ID needs to be purchased, by what user ID, etc... and this data can be packed in a boundary object called `Purchase_Request`.

While `Interactor` and `Boundary` require more explanation, I find that the word **Entities** is meaningful and can be grasped intuitively without reading any explanation.